# Asp.net MVC SqlCacheDependency

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sqlcachedependency

My application seems tobe taking time while loading data into a grid and I was looking for 
SqlCacheDependency are there any limitations of using this a part from retrieving when data is modified.

Also I was looking for some blogs/sample for  MVC application using SqlCacheDependency with entity framework any link/help on this would be of great help.